# User buys loads of consumable iaps, then restores them

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have an interesting question related to consumable iaps. It happened to me twice that from one specific country(probably the same user) have bought the same iap in the game (10-20 times), and on the other day he/she restores all of them. He/She bought the most expensive ($10) iap and it's pretty frustrating, because I think that he/she is buying the powerups and after using all of them, he/she simply restores them. i don't have a restore button, since it's not needed for consumables so I wonder how can the user do this and how can I eliminate these kind of actions?

Comment: What do you mean by "restores them"? As you have mentioned, consumable iaps can't be restored. Explain that part in detail please, how do you observe that restoring process?

Comment: In the "Sales and Trends" it appears that I've sold 10 iaps and the other day I've sold -10 iaps (The same iap 10 times, and the same iap -10 times). So I mean that the user maybe asks for refund at Apple or something like this.

Comment: Maybe, you got your app hacked? I don't think refund of the in app happens immediately.

Comment: Maybe it got hacked, but I don't think if somebody hacks an app would pay for iaps and would request for refund

Comment: It's not happening immediately, only the day after appears that I've sold -10 iaps.